# How to make DropDownList selection mandatory only if item list is not empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have two DropDownLists; ddl1 and ddl2, along with other controls in my web form. When user select an item from ddl1, the items are added in ddl2 accordingly from database. So there is a chance when no item added to ddl2 and it remains empty. I want mandatory to select the appropriate value from ddl2 if the listitem is not empty before submitting the webform (validation on ddl2 for submit button).

**UPDATED:**

```
<td class="col-46">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList14" runat="server" 
                AutoPostBack="True" 
                onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList14_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem>Select Current Class</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="-2">PG</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="-1">LKG</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="0">UKG</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>11</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>12</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>        
        </td>
        
                                <td class="col-46">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList15" runat="server">
            </asp:DropDownList>        
        </td>
```

and .aspx page:

```
protected void DropDownList14_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList15.Items.Clear();
        DropDownList15.ClearSelection();
        if (DropDownList14.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {
            DropDownList15.Items.Add("Select Section");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select distinct section from feestructure where class = '" + DropDownList14.SelectedValue + "' and session =@ssn", agr);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("ssn", DateTime.Parse(TextBox1.Text));
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                if (dr[0].ToString().Trim() != "")
                {
                    DropDownList15.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString().Trim());
                }
            }
            dr.Dispose();            
        }
    }
```

ddl1 => DropDownList14

ddl2 => DropDownList15

I want DropDownList15 selection mandatory (required validator) if it has items.

Comment: mark ddl2 html with a `required` property but keep ddl2 `disabled` until it's populated.

Comment: I've asp dropdownlist, how to do this. please provide code.

Comment: Please provide your HTML showing your markup and your code behind where ddl2 gets databound,

Comment: Yes, please provide your existing code, as far as you have it along with the existing behavior.  Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple. you can add required attribute in any dropdropdown. Create a dropdown like this and the add a RequiredFieldValidator for that dropdown.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="FirstDD" CssClass="form-control custom-select" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="FirstDD"
                                        CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="Required." />
```

and oncodebehind add this line..

```
 FirstDD.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select", ""));
```

or on aspx page add this line inside asp:DropDownList tag

```
<asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value=" "></asp:ListItem>
```